# Alarm Manager stops trigger PendingIntent after few moments

Tags: alarmmanager

I try to create reminder app. My aim is to trigger notification every hour. I have used Alarm Manager to achieve it. Everything works correctly for first 2-3 hours. After that time notifications stop being deliveried. If I reopen app I get missing notification imediatelly.

Alarm Manager:

```
val intent = Intent(context, AlarmReceiver::class.java).apply {
        action = context.getString(R.string.alarm_pending_action)
    }
val alarmIntent =  PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
val datetimeToAlarm = Calendar.getInstance()
        .apply {
            set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0)
            set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
            set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0)
        }
alarmManager.setRepeating(
        AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
        datetimeToAlarm.timeInMillis,
        60 * 60 * 1000,
        alarmIntent
)
```

AlarmReceiver:

```
override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
    if (intent.action != null) {
        if (intent.action!!.equals(context.getString(R.string.alarm_pending_action), ignoreCase = true)) {
            NotificationHelper.createNotification(context)
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest

```
<receiver android:name=".alert.AlarmReceiver"/>
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: I tried to use Service/IntentService instead of BroadcastReceiver. But nothing's changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. Solution is to replace `setRepeating` by `setAlarmClock` and it works well.